# AMPL - Step by Step mode

Tags: linear-programming

Is there a way to solve a problem using AMPL in a step by step(or a verbose, or a debug) mode? Preferably showing all basis exchanges?

The manuals of AMPL make reference to script development, but i didn't found anything about basis exchanges on these scripts.

I want to do this because i need to check if no mistakes were made while doing my model.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is more for the solver than for AMPL. E.g. Cplex has a `display` option to set the level of output for the Simplex LP solver.

Comment: To change the options of cplex on ampl IDE, one has to use the command "option cplex_options '<option of cplex>'". Example:

# Set the solver as cplex
option solver cplex;
# As Erwin pointed, this command shows output on every iteration
option cplex_options 'display=2';